# How to define an object property based on a if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, if-statement, datatables

I'm trying to configure the state of a datatable button based on a if/else statement.

The datatable button object:

```
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "button text",
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                button_action();
            },
            enabled: function () {
                if (column_exists) {
                    this.enabled = true
                } else {
                    this.enabled = false
                }
            }
      }
    ]
```

With this code, my button is always enabled. How can I set the `enabled` parameter correctly based on an if/else statement ?

Comment: This depends entirely on how the `enabled` function is called ?

Comment: ...and the value of `column_exists`.

Comment: Try a different variable name, since this.enabled will replace the enabled function with the value true. If that's what it supposed to be, use an IIFE to return true or false from inside the function.

Comment: what is the value of column_exists

Comment: The enabled parameter needs to be set to "true" or "false". I'm just not sure on how I can set this parameter correctly using an if/else statement. Is passing a function the correct way or am I redefining the parameter ?

Comment: Let's say the value of column_exists is sometimes 'true' and sometimes 'false'

Comment: Its not clear if you want this property to be computed on every call or just once. If the later `{enabled: !!column_exists}` Otherwise you can use custom getter `{ get enabled() {return !!column_exists}}`

Comment: Thank you guys, solved the problem with: `enabled: (!!column_exists)`

Comment: @kaycee If your `column_exists` is already a boolean you don't even need `!!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `enabled` to be true when `column_exists` is true, and the other way around.

So...

```
buttons: [
    {
        text: "button text",
        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
            button_action();
        },
        enabled: !!column_exists
    }
]
```

The `!!` is purely a precaution. It converts any value into a Boolean. If `column_exists` already was a Boolean, you would not need that.

---

That being said, the following is an antipattern.

```
if (somethingBoolean) {
    someValue = true;
} else {
    someValue = false;
}
```

Don't do that. Instead simply write:

```
someValue = somethingBoolean;
```

or coerce any value into a Boolean by double negation, as shown above.

```
someValue = !!anyValue;
```

Comment: Actually, column_exists is not a boolean but an object. So with the `!!` it works fine.

Comment: Note that an empty object `{}` is truthy, so `!!{}` gives you `true`. You might or might not want that, just be aware of it.

Comment: How do you know that function require (e, dt, node, config)? When this function has been defined? I don't understand sorry

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to make `enabled` a function but a boolean value.

For that, you can use an IIFE:

```
{
    enabled: (function () {
        if (column_exists) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }())
//   ^^
}
```

or just don't use if-else-statements but rather a ternary operator:

```
{
    enabled: column_exists ? true : false
}
```

which in your case can also be simplified to

```
{
    enabled: Boolean(column_exists)
}
```

Comment: @Tomalak Ooops. Thanks, fixed.